# How can I ignore this file "g4server.properties"

Tags: git, gitignore

```
➜  pms git:(v1) ✗ cat .gitignore 
/src/g4server.properties
/bin
.idea/
out/
pms.iml
➜  pms git:(v1) ✗ git status
# On branch v1
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   .gitignore
#   modified:   src/g4server.properties
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I have added `/src/g4server.properties` in .gitignore, but it seems it does't work. How can I ignore this `/src/g4server.properties` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possible options for you:

**remove src/g4server.properties completely from the git repository and then ignore it completely:**

```
git rm --cached src/g4server.properties
```

and add it to .gitignore.

**keep src/g4server.properties in the git repository but ignore future changes to this file**

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged src/g4server.properties
```

If you wanna start tracking changes again run the following command:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged src/g4server.properties
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because your file is in the index. Run `git rm --cached src/g4server.properties` and it will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot ignore files which are already tracked by git.

If you don't want to track that file you can remove it with `git rm --cached`.

Comment: you can ignore local changes with `update-index --skip-worktree` but you'd still get conflicts when pulling if file was changed on the remote

Answer (score 0):

With the leading `/` it points to the root of your filesystem. So make it local to the repository like this:

```
src/g4server.properties
```

in your .gitignore. Exactly as it's shown in the `git status` output.

Comment: Actually you are not correct. `/` points git to the root of the repository. Git doesn't ignore given file beacause it's added to the index.

Comment: @kaman Indeed, you are correct, just did a test. Both with and without leading `/` point to the same file and work alright. In that case no clue why it wouldn't work for OP. +1 on your answer then, learned something new again :)

Comment: The `/` points to the directory of the `.gitignore` file. Without the slash it would match any file with that name even if it is contained in some subdirectory.

Comment: Guys, I'm leaving the answer here for now, as you posted some valuable info. If you move it to your answers I will scrape this.

Comment: @michas that's correct I wrongly assumed that one would keep single ignore file in his project root.